# Zero float issue

Tags: c, floating

I have an issue about an expression which is that (10/3-3)*3-1. These numbers have to be float. And my code is below;

```
int main(){

    float a = 10;
    float b = 3;
    float c = 1;
    float result = (a/b-b)*b-c;
    printf("The result:%f\n", result);

}
```

**But, my result is also :**

`Result = -0.00000`

Why does happen like that ? How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: It's not an issue. It's just that floating point numbers have limited precission, and 10/3-3 is not exactly 1/3, because 1/3 cannot be stored with full precission.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Try `printf("The result:%e\n", result);`  (e vs f) to see more information.